# Compute $m$ so that the polynomial $R(x)$ has a root at $x=-3$

Tags: polynomials, roots

Apologies upfront, this is quite an elementary question, but I'm stuck here.

I'm asked to figure out the value of $m$ so that this polynomial: $$R(x)=x^2-mx+3$$ has a root at $x=-3$.

Following the definition of the [root of a polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolynomialRoots.html), $x=-3$ is a root if and only if $R(-3)=0$, which yields $\boxed{m=-12}$.

But in the other hand, following the [Factor Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem), if $x=-3$ is a root, then the polynomial $S(x)=(x+3)$ needs to be a factor of $R(x)$. Therefore, the remainder of $R(x)/S(x)$ needs to be $0$.

Applying [Ruffini's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini%27s_rule) with $x=-4$ I get the condition: $$3+3(3+m)=0$$ which is satisfied only in case $\boxed{m=-4}$

So I'm getting 2 different values for $m$, which is driving me crazy. I know this is a very basic question but I'm still wondering where I went wrong...

Thanks

Comment: Seems like I messed up the first calculation for m. Any way I could delete this post?

Comment: Jose, seriously, making a mistake in your work is okay.  And personally, I will upvote a question in which an asker shows their own work long before a question with a problem statement, period.  We all hit "blind spots" when checking our own work, so we all need other eyes here and there to help resolve any confusing results.

Comment: Your point was very valid, thank you @amWhy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you incorrectly performed your original calculation using the definition of a root of a polynomial. The calculation should look like this:
$$(-3)^2 - m(-3) + 3=0$$
$$9 + 3m + 3 = 0$$
$$12 + 3m = 0$$
$$12 = -3m$$
$$m=-4$$

Comment: Oh my world, what a mistake... I'm sorry

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia it’s okay. I make stupid mistakes like this quite often.

Answer (score 1):

You messed up your root of the polynomial method:

$$x^2 -mx + 3 = 0$$
$$(-3)^2 -m(-3) + 3 = 0$$
$$9 +3m+ 3 = 0$$
$$m = -4$$

Comment: Oops... I'm sorry for the error. I wish I could delete the question but it won't allow me to do so.

Comment: @Jose No need to delete the question.  You asked a fine question, showed your work, and it helped us all help you resolve the confusion.